# How to build WriteBuf from array

Tags: buffer, rust, traits

I am serializing two values in to an array and I am trying to go through a WriteBuf but I am getting the error that

```
error: the trait `std::io::Write` is not implemented for the type `[_; 12]`
error: type `std::io::buffered::BufWriter<&mut [_; 12]>` does not implement any method in scope named `write_be_u32`
error: type `std::io::buffered::BufWriter<&mut [_; 12]>` does not implement any method in scope named `write_be_f64`
```

Here is the minimum code to generate this error:

```
use std::io::{ BufWriter, Write };

fn main(){
  let packed_data = [0; 12];
  let timestamp : u32 = 100;
  let value : f64 = 9.9;

  let writer = BufWriter::new(&mut packed_data);
  writer.write_be_u32(timestamp);
  writer.write_be_f64(value);

  println!("Packed data looks like {:?}", packed_data);
}
```

Am I no borrowing the slice correctly? Am I note using the proper module to define the `Write` trait for my buffer?

Here is a playpen for this code: http://is.gd/ol8qND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few potential problems with your code:

- `packed_data` isn't mutable.
- You use `packed_data` at the end of `main` while `writer` holds a mutable reference to it.

I don't think that either of those things are causing the error. I did however find something that works:

```
use std::io::{ BufWriter, Write };

fn main() {
    let mut packed_data = [0; 12];

    {
        let packed_data_ref: &mut [u8] = &mut packed_data;
        let mut writer = BufWriter::new(packed_data_ref);

        writer.write(&[1, 2, 3, 4]).unwrap();
    } // `writer` gets deallocated and releases the mutable reference

    println!("Packed data looks like {:?}", packed_data);
}
```

[[playpen](http://is.gd/eZxn0Z)]

So I guess the issue is that you need a `&[u8]` rather than a `&[u8; 12]`. I have no idea why. I hope this at least helps though.

Comment: I was not complete in my description of the issue with my code. You solved the first error (the one I listed) for satisfying the trait `std::io::Write` but I want to use the `write_be_u32`/`write_be_f64` and those are not working. I will update the post with those errors.

Comment: @xrl: I believe that the `Writer` trait, which is what implements those methods, has been removed from the Rust standard library. So you are probably out of luck in that regard.

Comment: Adrian good catch! I'm not sure how I came across that old documentation and didn't realize it was old.